# Simple Proof by Induction

Tags: induction

I am asked to prove by induction that $4 + 9 + 14 + ... + 5n - 1 = \frac{n}{2}(3 + 5 n)$

As I understand it, during the induction step, one should replace $k$  by $k + 1$.

However, in the solution, the induction step is as follows

**Let $n = k$**

$4 + 9 + 14 + ... + (5k - 1) = \frac{k}{2}(3 + 5 k)$

**Assume $n = k + 1$**

$4 + 9 + 14 + ... + (5k - 1) + (5(k + 1) - 1) = \frac{k+1}{2}(3 + 5 (k+1))$

I don't understand on the LHS where the $(5k - 1)$ is coming from. Shouldn't $k$ be replaced by $k+1$, so that it looks like so

$4 + 9 + 14 + ... + (5(k + 1) - 1) = \frac{k+1}{2}(3 + 5 (k+1))$

Comment: Do you know the sum symbol $\sum$, it would be much clearier

Comment: The induction step must be: **assume** it true for $k$ and prove that it holds for $k+1$.

Comment: "Shouldn't $k$ be replaced by $k+1$": look closer, this is precisely what was done.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well, yes it should be, that is what confuses me. If you replace $k$ by $k+1$ in the line $let n = k$, then it should be as i showed on the last line. However, the actual answer is presented in $Assume n = k+1$, where a mysterious $5k-1$ appears in which the $k$ has not been replaced by $k+1$. Hope  this clears up my problem.

Comment: Thus you start from the identity with $k$: $\ldots +5(k+1)=\frac k 2 (3+5k)$ and write the LHS for the case  with $n=k+1$. It is the LHS of the previous formula with the "new term" for $n=k+1$ added. Then you rewrite it as $\frac k 2 (3+5k) + (5(k+1)-1)$ and you have to "manipulate" it to get the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply misunderstand the notation a little.

$$4 + 9 + 14 + ...  + (5(k + 1) - 1)$$

and

$$4 + 9 + 14 + ... + (5k - 1) + (5(k + 1) - 1)$$

are equivalent.

The writer just wanted to stress the addition of a term.